# Prolog - how to do setof that returns empty list instead of failing

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I need an ordered list of Objects that satisfy Goal. `setof` takes care of the ordering, but fails when no Objects satisfy Goal. I want to return an empty list instead like `findall` does.

This works, but is there a way of accomplishing this without a cut? I'm using SWI-Prolog.

```
setof(Object, Goal, List), !; List = [].
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First,

```
..., ( setof(Object, Goal, List), ! ; List = [] ), ...
```

does not work, as you suggest. It always succeeds for `List = []`, and it only shows the first answer of `setof/3`. But `setof/3` may produce several answers. The general method that works in any Prolog is:

```
..., ( \+ Goal -> List = [] ; setof(Object, Goal, List) ), ...
```

Many implementations offer an implementation specific control construct for this which avoids that `Goal` is called twice. E.g. `if/3` (SICStus, YAP), or `(*->)/2` (SWI, GNU):

```
..., if( setof(Object, Goal, ListX), ListX = List, List = [] ), ...

..., ( setof(Object, Goal, ListX) *-> ListX = List ; List = [] ), ...
```

The new variable `ListX` is necessary for the (admittedly rare) case that `List` is already instantiated.

<sub>Note that both other answers do not produce exactly what you asked for.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I guess jschimpf answer misses to preserve the generality you see in OP question. Hope I'm right on this, at least :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(setof(Object, Goal, List) ; List = [])
```

will work as well (setof itself is deterministic).

To be sure to get rid of the choice point, we need a bit more verbose

```
(setof(Object, Goal, List) -> true ; List = [])
```

*edit* as it stands, my answer is plainly wrong, or at least *very* incomplete. After false comments, and answer, I would suggest

```
setof(Object, Goal, List) *-> true ; List = [].
```

Comment: -1: Both answers are incorrect: The first will **always** produce a list, the second will remove wanted alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not need the potential nondeterminism or the variable-quantification features of setof**, you can stick with findall/3.  This is deterministic and doesn't fail:

```
?- findall(X, fail, Xs).
Xs = []
yes
```

You can then sort the results yourself using sort/2:

```
findall(Object, Goal, UnsortedWithDuplicates),
sort(UnsortedWithDuplicates, List)
```